# Remove page numbering for BEAMER's bibliography being out of frames

Tags: beamer, bibtex, multicol

I want a beamer presentation with my bibliography at the end. It should have a two-columns layout and a page number that, preferably, is inexistant (or that follows the page numbering from the last slide before the bibliography, even if a long bibliography is written over several slides).

I can get the bibliography to be written over several slides in the desired layout only if  the `\bibliography` argument is written outside of a `\frame` (or `\begin{frame}`) argument.

The problem is that I obtain a bibliography with a page number that is repeated all along the bibliography and is all the same (i.e., is blocked) since the last `\frame`. I have unsuccessfully tried several commands (e.g., `\nopagenumbering` or `\pagenumbering{gobble}` or `\pagestyle{empty}` or `\renewcommand{\thepage}{}`
).

Does someone has a solution or an idea ? Many thanks in advance !!

SkyR

Here is a reproducible example:
First the file called "refs.bib":

```
@article{a,
author = { Anat   Freund   PhD },
title = {Commitment and Job Satisfaction as Predictors of Turnover          Intentions Among Welfare Workers},
journal = {Administration in Social Work},
volume = {29},
number = {2},
pages = {5-21},
year  = {2005},
publisher = {Routledge}


}



@article{b,
author = { Louis A.   Penner  and  Alison R.   Midili  and  Jill       Kegelmeyer },
title = {Beyond Job Attitudes: A Personality and Social Psychology     Perspective on the Causes of Organizational Citizenship Behavior},
journal = {Human Performance},
volume = {10},
number = {2},
pages = {111-131},
year  = {1997},
publisher = {Routledge}

}

@article{c,
title = "The influence of job satisfaction on child welfare worker's desire     to stay: An examination of the interaction effect of self-efficacy and     supportive supervision",
journal = "Children and Youth Services Review",
volume = "32",
number = "4",
pages = "482 - 486",
year = "2010",
issn = "0190-7409",
author = "Szu-Yu Chen and Maria Scannapieco",
keywords = "Child welfare, Worker retention, Job satisfaction, Supervisor's     support, Work related self-efficacy"
}


@article{d,
title = "Job conditions, unmet expectations, and burnout in public child     welfare workers: How different from other social workers?",
journal = "Children and Youth Services Review",
volume = "33",
number = "2",
pages = "358 - 367",
year = "2011",
issn = "0190-7409",
author = "Hansung Kim",
keywords = "Child welfare, Job stress, Depersonalization, Social workers"
}

@article{e,
author = {Petersen, Michael Bang and Sznycer, Daniel and Cosmides, Leda and         Tooby, John},
title = {Who Deserves Help? Evolutionary Psychology, Social Emotions, and       Public Opinion about Welfare},
journal = {Political Psychology}}
```

Second, the main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\mode<presentation>{}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\vspace*{0.6cm}
\title[small title]{{\large{Big title}}}

\author[J. Deuf]{John Deuf}
\vspace{1cm}
\institute{ \Large{National center of research}

}

\date{1st of january 2043}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}        {\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace{2em}\null}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace{-1cm}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}
\section{Part1}
\frametitle{Title1}




\nocite{ a,b,c,d,e}



\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{frame}
\section{Part2}
\frametitle{Title2}




\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{frame}
\section{Part3}
\frametitle{Title3}

\end{frame}


{


\begin{multicols}{2}
\color{black}
\frametitle{} 
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\small

\bibliography{refs}
\end{multicols}


}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 5):

The following code should fullfil all your requirements except that it is not two column.

- You don't need `\usepackage{color} \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{graphics}` with beamer
- If your beamer version is reasonable up-to-date, you can use `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]` to add the frame numbers to the footline.
- you use a `plain` frame for your title page, you don't need to manually  remove the headline as a plain frame has no headline per default
- never use `\section`s inside of frames, they should only be used outside
- To split your bibliography frame over multiple slides, you could use the `allowframebreaks` option. `noframenumbering` will exclude it frame increasing the framennumber. Alternatively you could use `\appendix` before this frame.
- to not show any page numbers at all on the bibliography slides, they can be removed with `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}`
- The syntax `\large{Big title}` is incorrect, these font size commands are switches and don't take an argument. The correct syntax would be `\large Big title`, however it would be better to not place formatting instructions in the argument of macros like `\title` but to set the appropriate beamer font `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}`
- the line `\mode<presentation>{}` is superfluous and does nothing
- all the spacing instructions `\vspace*{0.6cm}` etc. in the preamble don't make sense

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
author = { Anat   Freund   PhD },
title = {Commitment and Job Satisfaction as Predictors of Turnover          Intentions Among Welfare Workers},
journal = {Administration in Social Work},
volume = {29},
number = {2},
pages = {5-21},
year  = {2005},
publisher = {Routledge}


}



@article{b,
author = { Louis A.   Penner  and  Alison R.   Midili  and  Jill       Kegelmeyer },
title = {Beyond Job Attitudes: A Personality and Social Psychology     Perspective on the Causes of Organizational Citizenship Behavior},
journal = {Human Performance},
volume = {10},
number = {2},
pages = {111-131},
year  = {1997},
publisher = {Routledge}

}

@article{c,
title = "The influence of job satisfaction on child welfare worker's desire     to stay: An examination of the interaction effect of self-efficacy and     supportive supervision",
journal = "Children and Youth Services Review",
volume = "32",
number = "4",
pages = "482 - 486",
year = "2010",
issn = "0190-7409",
author = "Szu-Yu Chen and Maria Scannapieco",
keywords = "Child welfare, Worker retention, Job satisfaction, Supervisor's     support, Work related self-efficacy"
}


@article{d,
title = "Job conditions, unmet expectations, and burnout in public child     welfare workers: How different from other social workers?",
journal = "Children and Youth Services Review",
volume = "33",
number = "2",
pages = "358 - 367",
year = "2011",
issn = "0190-7409",
author = "Hansung Kim",
keywords = "Child welfare, Job stress, Depersonalization, Social workers"
}

@article{e,
author = {Petersen, Michael Bang and Sznycer, Daniel and Cosmides, Leda and         Tooby, John},
title = {Who Deserves Help? Evolutionary Psychology, Social Emotions, and       Public Opinion about Welfare},
journal = {Political Psychology}}    
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
%\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
%\mode<presentation>{}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\Large}

%\vspace*{0.6cm}
\title[small title]{Big title}

\author[J. Deuf]{John Deuf}
%\vspace{1cm}
\institute{National center of research}


\date{1st of january 2043}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]
%\addtobeamertemplate{footline}        {\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace{2em}\null}

\begin{document}

%{
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
%\vspace{-1cm}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
%}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Part1}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title1}




\nocite{ a,b,c,d,e}



\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Part2}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title2}




\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Part3}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title3}

\end{frame}


\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\color{black}
\frametitle{} 
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\small

\bibliography{\jobname}
%\end{multicols}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and the tips ! But indeed, I need a two-column layout, it is exactly on that aspect that I am stuck... As far as I know, we can have a two-column layout only out of frames, and we can remove the page numbering only inside a frame... so how to have a two-column layout without page numbering ?... that is the question. :-)

Comment: @SkyR beamer is really not meant to have content outside of frames. This all relies on beamer's ability to recover from unexpected input, I would not trust it.

Comment: @SkyR Off-topic and a matter of personal taste: your choice of bibliography style in combination with a multicolumn layout will result in very short lines and many unfavourable line breaks. For better readability, I would use only a single column.

Comment: Yes, thank you, you are probably right, I should use a 1 column layout. I just wanted to have a two column-layout and this worked only out of frames, I don't know why. Then I was upset not to be able to find the solution of my initial requirements: two-column layout + absence of pagenumbering.... I am still sure that a solution to get this does exist. Then, if it is apropriate, better for visibility or not, it is a different topic :-)