# Remove page numbering in the Bibliography in Beamer using Biber

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am trying to remove the page numbers appearing in my printed bibliography slides in beamer (using biber) without using the `plain` option in the `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]`.

My question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457251/remove-page-numbering-for-beamers-bibliography-being-out-of-frames). However, the proposed solution:

```
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\color{black}
\frametitle{} 
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\small

\bibliography{\jobname}
%\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
```

Does not work for me when adapted to:

```
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]{Bibliography}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
  \printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
\end{frame}
```

As I always get:

[image]

Here is my tex code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=apa, citestyle = apa, sortcites=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Bibliography/Short_Library.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} 
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\tiny} 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}
\usepackage{dirtytalk} 
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\newenvironment{trienv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]}}{}
\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{rotating} 

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Citations}
    In text 1: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item \parencite{BCBS_RCAP2013_RWA}
    \item \parencite{BCBSNewMotto2013,BCBSNewMotto2014}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Citations}
    In text 2: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textcite{Altman2005DRlinkLGD}
    \item \textcite{Gordy2003,Cespedes2020LGDPDModel}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]{Bibliography}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
  \printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

And my bib file:

```
@techreport{BCBSNewMotto2013,
author = {{BCBS}},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
institution = {Bank for International Settlements},
isbn = {9291319406},
number = {October},
pages = {1--23},
title = {{Discussion paper - The regulatory framework: balancing risk sensitivity, simplicity and comparability}},
url = {https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs258.htm},
year = {2013}
}

@techreport{BCBS_RCAP2013_RWA,
author = {BCBS},
institution = {Bank for International Settlements},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
abstract = {This document is called BCBS 256. This is where it all started (Basel IV). This document outlines for the first time "formally" the huge variability registered within the RWA computations across banks.},
isbn = {929131966X},
keywords = {BCBS},
number = {October},
pages = {57},
title = {{Regulatory Consistency Assessment Programme (RCAP) – Analysis of risk-weighted assets for credit risk in the banking book}},
year = {2013}
}

@techreport{BCBSNewMotto2014,
abstract = {This document is called BCBS 306. This document introduces for the first time the motto: greater simplicity, comparability and risk sensitivity of the risk-weighted assets computations.},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
author = {{BCBS}},
isbn = {9789291973804},
keywords = {BCBS},
number = {December 2014},
pages = {12},
institution = {{Bank for International Settlements}},
title = {{Consultative document - Capital floors: the design of a framework based on standardised approaches}},
year = {2014}
}

@article{Gordy2003,
author = {Gordy, Michael B.},
doi = {10.1016/S1042-9573(03)00040-8},
isbn = {1042-9573},
issn = {10429573},
journal = {Journal of Financial Intermediation},
keywords = {Banking regulation,Capital allocation,Value-at-risk},
number = {3},
pages = {199--232},
title = {{A risk-factor model foundation for ratings-based bank capital rules}},
volume = {12},
year = {2003}
}

@article{Cespedes2020LGDPDModel,
  title={{Random LGD adjustments in the Vasicek credit risk model}},
  author={Garc{\'\i}a-C{\'e}spedes, Rub{\'e}n and Moreno, Manuel},
  journal={The European Journal of Finance},
  doi={https://doi.org/10.1080/1351847X.2020.1789685},
  volume={26},
  number={18},
  pages={1856--1875},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{Altman2005DRlinkLGD,
  title={{The Link between Default and Recovery Rates: Theory, Empirical Evidence, and Implications}},
  author={Altman, Edward I and Brady, Brooks and Resti, Andrea and Sironi, Andrea},
  journal={The Journal of Business},
  volume={78},
  number={6},
  doi={https://doi.org/10.1086/497044},
  pages={2203--2228},
  year={2005},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
```

I have tried many combinations using solutions that work in the article class, but nothing seems to work in beamer, e.g., `\nopagenumbering` or `\pagenumbering{gobble}`

Any suggestions on how I can solve that issue?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- your document won't compile due to an error in the bibliography. Use `\'i` instead of `\'\i`
- [As said before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665693/biblatex-in-beamer-not-adding-extradate-letter#comment1655342_665693), you don't need to load the `graphicx` and `hyperref` packages, beamer loads them for you
- [As said before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665693/biblatex-in-beamer-not-adding-extradate-letter#comment1655342_665693), better not mess with the link colours, this will destroy beamer's carefully set up colour themes
- as you are overwriting the normal footline with `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`, you have to redefine the footline in order to remove the frame numbers

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=apa, citestyle = apa, sortcites=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{BCBSNewMotto2013,
author = {{BCBS}},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
institution = {Bank for International Settlements},
isbn = {9291319406},
number = {October},
pages = {1--23},
title = {{Discussion paper - The regulatory framework: balancing risk sensitivity, simplicity and comparability}},
url = {https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs258.htm},
year = {2013}
}

@techreport{BCBS_RCAP2013_RWA,
author = {BCBS},
institution = {Bank for International Settlements},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
abstract = {This document is called BCBS 256. This is where it all started (Basel IV). This document outlines for the first time "formally" the huge variability registered within the RWA computations across banks.},
isbn = {929131966X},
keywords = {BCBS},
number = {October},
pages = {57},
title = {{Regulatory Consistency Assessment Programme (RCAP) – Analysis of risk-weighted assets for credit risk in the banking book}},
year = {2013}
}

@techreport{BCBSNewMotto2014,
abstract = {This document is called BCBS 306. This document introduces for the first time the motto: greater simplicity, comparability and risk sensitivity of the risk-weighted assets computations.},
address = {Basel, Switzerland},
author = {{BCBS}},
isbn = {9789291973804},
keywords = {BCBS},
number = {December 2014},
pages = {12},
institution = {{Bank for International Settlements}},
title = {{Consultative document - Capital floors: the design of a framework based on standardised approaches}},
year = {2014}
}

@article{Gordy2003,
author = {Gordy, Michael B.},
doi = {10.1016/S1042-9573(03)00040-8},
isbn = {1042-9573},
issn = {10429573},
journal = {Journal of Financial Intermediation},
keywords = {Banking regulation,Capital allocation,Value-at-risk},
number = {3},
pages = {199--232},
title = {{A risk-factor model foundation for ratings-based bank capital rules}},
volume = {12},
year = {2003}
}

@article{Cespedes2020LGDPDModel,
  title={{Random LGD adjustments in the Vasicek credit risk model}},
  author={Garc{\'i}a-C{\'e}spedes, Rub{\'e}n and Moreno, Manuel},
  journal={The European Journal of Finance},
  doi={https://doi.org/10.1080/1351847X.2020.1789685},
  volume={26},
  number={18},
  pages={1856--1875},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{Altman2005DRlinkLGD,
  title={{The Link between Default and Recovery Rates: Theory, Empirical Evidence, and Implications}},
  author={Altman, Edward I and Brady, Brooks and Resti, Andrea and Sironi, Andrea},
  journal={The Journal of Business},
  volume={78},
  number={6},
  doi={https://doi.org/10.1086/497044},
  pages={2203--2228},
  year={2005},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} 
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\tiny} 

%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{
%    colorlinks,
%    linkcolor={},
%    citecolor={blue},
%    urlcolor={blue}
%}
\usepackage{dirtytalk} 
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\newenvironment{trienv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]}}{}
\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{rotating} 

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Citations}
    In text 1: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item \parencite{BCBS_RCAP2013_RWA}
    \item \parencite{BCBSNewMotto2013,BCBSNewMotto2014}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Citations}
    In text 2: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textcite{Altman2005DRlinkLGD}
    \item \textcite{Gordy2003,Cespedes2020LGDPDModel}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
  \printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, "again", @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Regarding the hyperref , I prefer to use it, as otherwise the "citecolor" is "black" in my "Gordy, 2003" and I need to have them in blue. Is there perhaps a safer way to modify it?